# limited number of rows ( N rows )only while executing the DB2 Select Query in Perl Script

Tags: perlscript

How can I get limited number of rows ( N rows )only while executing the DB2 Select Query in Perl Script As we Do in DB2 i.e. Fetch N rows only ? How can We arrange the fetched rows as Ascending or Descending ?

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: . /db2/$DB_INSTANCE/sqllib/db2profile;
db2 connect to $DB_NAME

db2 "DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT F.ID,I.AID FROM TAMPP01.FACE F, TAMPP01.IDEAS I, TAMPP01.IDEAS_GRP ID, TAMPP01.NAMES NS WHERE F.ID = NS.ID AND F.ID = I.ID AND I.ID = ID.ID FETCH FIRST 5000 RECORDS ONLY WITH UR"

db2 "load from C1 OF CURSOR MESSAGES insert into $SCHEMA_NAME.FACET_ARCHIVE(ID, AID) nonrecoverable " > $BATCH_TEMP_DIR/loadReRunRSRCResult.out

I HAVE USED THE ABOVE STATEMENTS TO GET 5000 RECORDS AND INSERT THEM TO ANOTHER TABLE

Comment: I am new to perl Scripting. Don't have enough knowledge about it. Plz help with it.